# Determine port for SSDT publish in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, port, sql-server-data-tools, msbuild-wpp

How can I determine the port that is being used when I publish an SSDT project from Visual Studio 2013?

I need to know the port to troubleshoot an access issue. I looked at the Advanced Properties for the connection, but I couldn't find that information.

[image: Advanced Properties]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the normal sql rules so the default instance is tcp 1433 (by default).

Connect via ssms and look at the errorlog, near the beginning it will say listening on xxx.

To get to the errorlog via ssms, go to: "Management-->Sql Server Logs"

If you are having trouble connecting:

-Find out if the instance is listening on tcp, get the port I it is, enqble it if it isn't

-Use telnet to try to connect to the port from the client, if you get a blank screen then it is open

-If you get a connection refused then sql probably isn't listening on that port

-If you get a connection timeout you probably have a firewall blocking the port

Ed

Comment: What errorlog are you referring to? And where can it be found?

Comment: Connect to sql using ssms and it is under maintenance - what are the connection issues you are getting? Also I know you have blanked  the connection string out, can you show what you have but replace anything sensitive with * or something?

Comment: The connection string is not the issue as the same string works on other machines. Where is the maintenance in ssms? I don't see maintenance at the top or in the right click menu.

Comment: Management-->Sql Server Logs

Comment: When you find the log, you are looking for something like "Server is listening on [Any<ipv4/6> XXXX]"

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't access the SQL Server Logs. However if you add the additional detail about how to get to the SQL Server Logs I'll accept your answer.